# Qt android Creator : Invalid Qt Version

Tags: android, qt

I have installed "Necessitas" qt creator and then I have installed the "Ministro" now when I push run it open the phone emulator and then I get:

```
invalid qt version
```

how can I fix this issue ? 
note that am using  Qt 4.8.3 (32 bit) and Ministro II v9.5.apk

Regards

Comment: Any reason not to use Qt5?

Comment: how can i update to Qt5 ?

Comment: Get "Qt 5.1.1 for Android" for your host system from http://qt-project.org/downloads